# $post in wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, loop

How do I get the $post Variable in a WP_Query started loop?
I have to get the excerpt, raw $post->post_content and further things. This is why I have to get Access to the Variable itself.

How am I able to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // this fills in the $post global with the next post from the query
    $query->the_post();
    // we're now ina  classic wordpress loop, and can use all the usual stuff
    the_title();
    the_content();
    echo $post->post_content;
}
// lets clean up after ourself so else we might mess up other queries and function calls
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $your_query->have_posts() ) :
    $your_query->the_post();

    echo $your_query->post->post_content;

endwhile;
```